# How to create a mail counter for each Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I want to count the number of submission received for every contact form.

I've tried to use the method of sevenspark adding in functions.php from below link

http://sevenspark.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-counter-for-contact-form-7

But i'll receive always count=1

Someone can help me?

Thanks
Manoj Rajendran

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and its working well by using contact form 7 serial number plugin. No need for any coding just install add the shortcode.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-serial-numbers/

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Is there a way to print it on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the increment function is being called? Did you check if your changes where persisted? Is the mail sent each time? Did you reload the Page after submitting the form?